# Resources to learn about testing theory

Tags: automated-testing

Can anyone recommend some good resources (books, perhaps) to dive into the theory of testing?

(I don't mean "what is a test plan", but more on the level of "use these techniques to make your tests robust" or the like).

Comment: Having posted my answer I noticed you tagged your question with 'automated testing' - why? Do you want to know about testing or automation - or both?

Comment: @PhilKirkham Thanks for your excellent answer! Unfortunately, at least one tag is mandatory, so I chose that.

Comment: I would turn this question into a community wiki, as there cannot be "the best" answer for this kind of questions.

Comment: @dzieciou I would if I knew how. I hit edit, and there's no option to do that.

Answer (score 2):

[Practitioners Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158053791X) to S/W test design by Lee Copeland

[Systematic S/W Testing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580535089) by Rick Craig

These got me started off learning techniques
Then start reading stuff by Cem Kaner, James Bach, Jerry Weinberg....

Answer (score 2):

Becoming a software testing expert by James Bach

Testing computer software by Cem Kaner, Jack Falk & Hung Quoc Nguyen

Lateral thinking by Edward de Bono

Lessons learned in software testing by James Bach

Perfect software and other illusions of software testing by Jerry Weinberg

Comment: Here's James Bach's talk on Becoming a Software Testing Expert: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhfVK_ubk8U

Answer (score 2):

Free online resources could be found on http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST/

Start with foundations and do all the readings.

Answer (score 2):

As Karlo mentions (I'll explain a little more) the [Black Box Software Testing](http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST) (BBST) courses are the most in-depth courses I've ever taken (or seen). They are university-level courses so they contain a TON of information from a wide-variety of sources. Take a look at this diagram explaining the emphasis for each of the BBST courses:

[image]

Testing Knowledge, learning skills and testing skills are the main emphasis for 4 available courses. The courses are:

- BBST: Foundations
- BBST: Bug Advocacy
- BBST: Test Design
- BBST: Domain Testing

BBST Foundations is the first course. The materials are available online [here](http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST) free for the first 3 courses. Then next course (domain testing) is proprietary so you'll have to find someone who teaches them. There's also a workbook for BBST Foundations on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0989811921) and there's at least one review (mine) on the workbook.

The classes are a great way to get an introduction to testing theory because they gradually introduce you to concepts and then provide you with even more (20+) references that you'll be able to use to gain more information, including half a dozen or so book recommendations. The [Association for Software Testing](http://www.associationforsoftwaretesting.org) runs regular classes for their members.

Cem Kaner's publication list on his [website](http://kaner.com/?page_id=7) has hundreds of references related to software testing that I suggest you skim. Also skim the BBST website.

If you want more resources than this, just ask. =)

Answer (score 1):

A good online (and free) class is Udacity's [Software Testing](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs258) course. It covers a lot of theory.

Comment: Udacity's course covers some theory but it's more geared towards glass-box testing (which can be useful).

Answer (score 1):

A great place to read through testing theory is the Software Testing Club and the Ministry of Testing. I read their content all the time and it always answers a question or gets me to think differently about certain testing scenarios.

http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/